# why my google map iframe didn't fill all the blank space in Safari?

Tags: html, css, google-maps, iframe, safari

I had embedded my google map in the iframe, and it look perfectly in all the browser, however when view with safari, there are grey space at the top of the google map, it didn't filled out the width of the border I set.
Why?

My coding

```
<div class="demo-wrapper">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m27!1m12!1m3!1d3197457.709806509!2d-98.32007789999999!3d38.498778899999984!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m12!1i0!3e6!4m3!3m2!1d38.8547169!2d-98.2212009!4m5!1s0x87a31771717c016b%3A0x68c2b4a94b3e095f!2sKansas!3m2!1d39.011902!2d-98.4842465!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1406182467742" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.demo-wrapper {
border: 3px solid #424242;
width: 485px;
height: 300px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

here is the image when I preview in different browser.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz4nKzGACTZRVEotbXNqU3kxcVU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try to give `margin:0; and padding:0` to body tag. check **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yaqeyiwe/1)**.

```
body {margin:0; padding:0; border:0;}
```

Comment: not working, there are still grey space at the top of the google map when browse in Safari.

Comment: I've checked in safrai and I didn't see any border. It seems some other CSS are culprit for this issue. can you post a link?